# javascript V8 optimisation and "leaking arguments"

Tags: javascript, v8

I read in [various places](http://reefpoints.dockyard.com/2014/09/22/javascript-performance-for-the-win.html) that it's advisable to be careful with the `arguments` object and that this is ok...

```
    var i = arguments.length, args = new Array(i);
    while (i--) args[i] = arguments[i];
```

But, is this ok or not?...

```
function makeArray (l) {
    var i = l.length, array = new Array(i);
    while (i--) array[i] = l[i];
    return array;
};
//...
//EDIT: put the function on an object to better represent the actual case
var o = {};
o.f = function (callback) {
    var args = makeArray (arguments);
    callback.apply(args[0] = this, args);
};
```

What is meant by "leaking arguments" and how does it affect optimisation?

I am focused on V8, but I assume it applies to other compilers as well?

to prove it works...

```js
function makeArray (l) {
    var i = l.length, array = new Array(i);
    while (i--) array[i] = l[i];
    return array;
};
//...
//EDIT: put the function on an object to better represent the actual case
var o = {};
o.f = function (callback) {
    var args = makeArray (arguments);
    callback.apply(args[0] = this, args);
};
o.m = "Hello, ";
function test(f, n) {
    alert(this.m + " " + n)
}
o.f(test, "it works...")
```

Comment: Instead of `var o={}; o.f=function(){ [code] };`, you should have  `var o={f:function(){ [code] }};`.

Comment: In fact they are equivalent ;)

Comment: Yes, they are. But the difference is that you are creating an object with a method using the code I provived. With your code, you create an empty object and then you modify it to insert a new method.

Comment: Well, the end result is the same.  I did it that way to more closely model the actual code that I'm analysing. I'm aware that there are a few ways to do it but why do you recommend doing it the way you suggest? Any particular reason?

Comment: There are 2 advantages that come to my mind: 1- The most basic one is the syntax itself. You can declare every method and property right there, without any changes. You don't need to fiddle around to look where the heck a method/property is being defined. 2- Since you do everything at once, the compiler may optimize the code when creating the object and when any method/property is accessed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem with `arguments` is same as with local `eval` and `with`: they cause aliasing. [Aliasing defeats all sorts of optimizations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_(computing)#Conflicts_with_optimization) so even if you enabled optimization of these kind of functions you would probably end up just wasting time which is a problem with JITs because the time spent in the compiler is time not spent running code (although some steps in the optimization pipeline can be run in parallel).

Aliasing due to `arguments` leaking:

```
function bar(array) {    
    array[0] = 2;
}

function foo(a) {
    a = 1;
    bar(arguments);
    // logs 2 even though a is local variable assigned to 1
    console.log(a);
}
foo(1);
```

Note that strict mode eliminates this:

```
function bar(array) {    
    array[0] = 2;
}

function foo(a) {
    "use strict";
    a = 1;
    bar(arguments);
    // logs 1 as it should
    console.log(a);
}
foo(1);
```

Strict mode however isn't optimized either and I don't know any reasonable explanation except that benchmarks don't use strict mode and strict mode is rarely used. That might change since many es6 features require strict mode, otoh `arguments` is not needed in es6 so...

Comment: Ok, but the only way to optimise is to put the while loop to copy `arguments` inside the original function, can't out-source it... right?

Answer (score 1):

This is a 2-fold problem:

1. You lose any and all possible optimizations and branch predictions
   The `arguments` object is unpredictible.
2. You leak memory. Really bad!

Consider the following code (run it at your own risk!):

```js
function a(){return arguments;}

x=a(document.getElementsByTagName('*'));

window._interval=setInterval(function(){

    for(var i=0;i<1e6;i++)
    {
        x=a(x);
    }
},5000);
```

```css
*{font-family:sans-serif;}
```

```html
<p>Warning! This may overheat your cpu and crash your browser really badly!</p>

<p>I'm not responsible for any software and hardware damages!</p>

<p><b>Run at your own risk!!!</b></p>

<p>If you ran this code, press F5 to stop or close the browser.</p>

<p>If you want, you can try to <button onclick="window.clearInterval(window._interval);window.x='';">stop it</button>. (the RAM may remain unchanged)</p>
```

And now watch your RAM go up, when you run that (it goes up at a rate of around 300-500MB every 5 seconds).
A naive implementation that simply passes the arguments around may cause these problems.

Not to mention that your code will (generally) be a tad slower.

---

Note that this:

```js
function a(){return arguments;}
function b(arg){return arg;}

x=a(document.getElementsByTagName('*'));

window._interval=setInterval(function(){

    for(var i=0;i<1e6;i++)
    {
        x=b(x);
    }
},5000);
```

```css
*{font-family:sans-serif;}
```

```html
<p>This may be safe, but be careful!</p>

<p>I'm not responsible for any software and hardware damages!</p>

<p><b>Run at your own risk!!!</b></p>

<p>If you ran this code, press F5 to stop or close the browser.</p>

<p>If you want, you can try to <button onclick="window.clearInterval(window._interval);window.x='';">stop it</button>.</p>
```

Won't have the same effect as the code before.
This is because `b()` returns the same variable, instead of a new reference to a new `arguments` object.
This is a **very** important difference.

Comment: Won't `function a(arg){return arg;}` yield the same result?

Comment: @CoolBlue No, in that case you are returning the same variable. In my case, you are returning the reference of a **new `arguments` object**, over and over again.

Comment: @CoolBlue I've added a code to show my point. You can try it. But be **very** careful.

Comment: You're returning `arguments` which leaves a closure in `a` and a circular reference through `arguments.callee`. It's a memory leak perfect storm... My example is adding a reference to a new  `arguments` object  in the makeArray call but I'm not leaving any closures after `f`` completes. What am I missing? I don't see a memory leak in my example.

Comment: @CoolBlue I don't see any closures. And your code still has (somewhat) partially the same functioning as the first example. Your code passes the `arguments` object to another function to then be used to call another function, which is included in the `arguments` object, where you assign the `window` object to it.

Comment: Yes, your right... I oversimplified it.  I edited it to be more like the actual code. (and it's not mine by the way).

Comment: @CoolBlue You have the exact same code, but now you have 2 errors: you are creating a variable `o` and attributing it an object and then you are creating the variable `o.f` (this should be a `SyntaxError`) and assigning it a function with the same exact code, but now you assign the `this` in the `arguments` object, which will cause a recursion in memory. You should have `var o={f:function(){ [code] }};`.