# why mutating arguments can cause unoptimizable?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here in [bluebird article](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#32-leaking-arguments), it's said:

> The arguments object must not be passed or leaked anywhere.

And it has some bad examples as below:

```
function leaksArguments1() {
    return arguments;
}

function leaksArguments2() {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
}
```

I didn't get why this can cause unoptimizable. Thanks.

Comment: Because a fully-functional sloppy-mode `arguments` object is really heavy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript interpreter in modern browsers is doing lots of optimizations, which are turned off if `arguments` is leaked outside of a function. It is mentioned in [mdn documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

[image]

I found the perfect explanation to this in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30237178/8438534)